# GameRequestDialog for Facebook friend invitation always asks for login, even if user was already logged in

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, facebook-invite

I am using GameRequestDialog from Facebook to enable game invitations to my users. The problem is, when my users are logged in with their Facebook App on Android(single sign-on feature), it always asks for another login when they try to run GameRequestDialog. The second login is web view based, and user has to fill in whole login and password manually. It is a nightmare, who would do that, if first login was just one click? I have this problem both on Android and IOS. It works like this in official Facebook Examples (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/RPSSample/src/com/example/rps) and in Cordova Facebook lugin (https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4). I have checked multiple apps in app store, and many have similar problem like I do. But there are some, that can use GameRequestDialog with just one initial login. For example Coin Master requires only first Facebook connect(Single sign on), and you can later invite friends with GameRequestDialog without addition login.

Comment: I am facing the same issue as well. Here is my post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57709126/facebook-android-sdk-graph-api-3-2-and-4-0-sending-app-request-issue

Answer (score 0):

On Android, try using com.facebook.gamingservices.GameRequestDialog instead of com.facebook.share.widget.GameRequestDialog